# Removing mysql from Ubuntu 16.04 creates issues while reinstalling it

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I needed to delete mysql from ubuntu 16.04. After deleting it, found that I got myself into trouble and cannot reinstall it normally. I also cleaned my system by `sudo apt-get clean`.
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server` does not work properly and also tried reinstalling it but could not help. 
Why reinstalling a mysql is creating a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Your question is clear (great!), but the underlying explanation as of *what* goes wrong, needs some expanding: how do you know that the reinstallation did not work? What is the "problem" you are experiencing?

Comment: @agtoever the error I get after re-installing mysql [

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: The package manager (dpkg) gets an error. Could you please provide a more complete log of what goes wrong and add it to your question?

Comment: Whatever I try and try to remove mysql for fresh installing it. It has same error
`If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.7, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`